# Simple PHP function to check user rank not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a simple PHP script to get the rank of a user which would then determine whether or not they have access to view the contents of that page.

However, it doesn't work. No matter what the user's rank is, it still shows the content. This is my script:

```
<?php

include "db_connect.php";
include "auth.php";

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$getrank = "SELECT rank FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $getrank);

if ($result == 3) {
    echo 'You do not have permission to view this page. Redirecting you...';
    header( "Refresh:5; url=index.php", true, 303);

} else {
    echo 'you can view'; //just a text placeholder for debugging purposes
}

?>
```

The ranks are set in my MySQL db as either 1, 2 or 3, where I only want access allowed to the users with ranks 1 and 2.

I realize that this method of rank authentication is not ideal and that a user could easily bypass this by pressing ESC before it redirects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to fetch an array http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: `if($result = 3)` - you're assigning the value `3` to the variable `$result`, you're not checking anything. Is this a typo? There should be two equals (`==`) there if you want to assert that the `$result` is equal to 3.

Comment: @Drown yes sorry, that is a typo. It's == . edited it. no matter what the user's rank is, it still shows me "you can view"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want like this code try this.

```
<?php

include "db_connect.php";
include "auth.php";

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$getrank = "SELECT rank FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $getrank);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($row['rank'] == 3) {
    echo 'You do not have permission to view this page. Redirecting you...';
    header( "Refresh:5; url=index.php", true, 303);

} else {
    echo 'you can view'; //just a text placeholder for debugging purposes
}

?>
```